# Using `signInWithRedirect` with an `authDomain` different than the domain of the app does not complete the sign in (and reports no errors)

Tags: javascript, next.js, firebase-authentication

I'm migrating Firebase `signInWithPopup` to `signInWithRedirect`.

If I don't implement the best practices listed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices#proxy-requests), the login works fine on Chrome (but not on Firefox and Safari as the documentation states). Implementing the Option #3 of the documentation (which changes the `authDomain` of Firebase's configuration to point to our servers, and adds a proxy to rewrite the URLs to Firebase's domain), makes this work on all browsers on my dev environment (where I use a real Firebase project, not an emulation).

The issue happens on the staging environment, where I have different deployments (that are deployed on each PR, with unique URLs), that all point to the main staging URL as the `authDomain` (let's call it "www.staging.com" ). As they are all unique URLs I cannot allow them all in Google's OAuth list, which is the reason they all point to "www.staging.com", instead of "www.randomUrl123.com" (as an example of one of the PR deployments).

Unfortunately, the sign in does not succeed on "www.randomUrl123.com". It redirects to Google, and then redirects back to "www.randomUrl123.com", but no sign in happens, and `getRedirectResult` returns `null` instead of throwing an error.
The browser console is also empty, so I'm not really sure how to debug this.

Any clues on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is currently not possible: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7824